# How can I restrict element width, using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK, I'm having an issue I really can't get my head around...

My website is built around Twitter Bootstrap and I'm showing data in a Nested Accordion structure.

However, on some cases (such as this one : http://patternz.drkameleon.com/project/results/441298/3/extended - please have a look at the 'Results' tab, it needs a Username: 'peraspera' and Password: 'adastra' to access it), **the content seems to overflow**.

If you want to see the actual code (and not what it looks like, since this one is fetched via AJAX, the content is here : http://patternz.drkameleon.com/project/format/441298/3/extended).

The weird thing is that in various other cases the content is properly restricted inside the main page...

Any ideas what might be going wrong or what could be done in order to fixes?

---

Anything will be more than welcome - I've been banging my head against the wall several hours due to this thing... :S

Comment: style='width:100%' on your fieldset.

Comment: It got stuck at 99.91% for me

Comment: @Orangepill I've added a `width:100%` almost to every possible element, but it's still not working... :S

Comment: @PatsyIssa It didn't get stuck - it just takes a couple more seconds...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Updated that width to 100% in chrome dev tools and it worked ... maybe there is a style that is overriding it.... I put it directly on the element.

Comment: @Orangepill Hmm... I may be missing something, on which element exactly did you set width to 100%?

Comment: The only fieldset element under the results tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width:900px` to `tab-pane` class

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="patterns" style="width:900px">
```

[image]

Comment: You're my hero! THANKS A LOT, buddy! Oh, you've saved me sooooo much time!!! Have a great day! :-)